# What is the difference between "Chargé d'affaires" and "minister resident"?

Tags: meaning, difference

what is the difference between "Chargé d'affaires" and "minister resident"?
are they the same ? i need clarification.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charg%C3%A9_d%27affaires

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_(title)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to Wikipedia
["Diplomatic Rank"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_rank)

I found this statement in the article:
"Ministers resident formed an intermediate class, between ministers and chargés. This rank was created by the Congress of Aix-la-Chapelle."

I get the impression that "minister" is an obsolete term, but I suggest you consult the article above to be sure.